# standalone and lineno producing big white spaces

Tags: standalone, lineno

With line numbering on a 95 lines text inside a longer document, I have bad interactions between line numbering and the standalone package.
I have huge (and unwanted) white spaces added:[image: line 54 should be on the top of page 7, and it's in the middle after a big skip!]

The text can be correctly displayed if I:

- remove the line numbering just by removing \linenumbers
- remove the standalone class (it's a subdocument) and replace it with the \documentclass of the document:

With

```
\documentclass[class=exam_DH, crop=false,bold,11pt,titlepage,twoside,nocenter,upper,a4paper,final,answers]{standalone}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true]{standalone}
```

the problem appears, with

```
\documentclass[bold,12pt,titlepage,twoside,nocenter,upper,a4paper,final,answers]{exam_DH}
```

it's not there.
Any idea, solution allowing to use simultaneously standalone and lineno in this document?

Comment: As for exam_DH, ctan can't find it either.  Line numbers are put into the margins, and standalone doesn't have margins.  Why don't you set up the page with geometry instead?

Comment: exam_DH is my customization around the "exam" class, https://ctan.org/pkg/exam . I didn't show it there, but my full preambule invoke geometry, with \geometry{hmargin=1cm,bmargin=1.2cm,textheight=27cm, textwidth=19cm, footskip=1ex}. All the preambule is the same, but the 2 lines I reported.